# How to echo error message if include can't find the file

Tags: php

I use a php script to include another php file. When someone goes to the index.php with the wrong string, I want it to show on the screen an error message.

How do I make it show a custom error message like "You have used the wrong link. Please try again."?

Here is what I am doing now...

Someone comes to the URL like this...

```
 http://example.com/?p=14
```

That would take them to the `index.php` file and it would pick up `p`. In the `index.php` script it then uses `include ('p'.$p.'/index.php');` which finds the directory `p14` and includes the `index.php` file in that directory.

I am finding people, for what ever reason, are changing the `p=` and making it something that is not a directory. I want to fight against that and just show an error if they put anything else in there. I have too many directories and will be adding more so I can't just us a simple `if ($p != '14'){echo "error";}` I would have to make about 45 of those.

So what is a simple way for me to say.... "If include does not work then echo "error";"?

Comment: You can call [`file_exists()`](http://php.net/file_exists) before trying to include it.   If it doesn't exist, show an error.  You should sanitize/filter `$p` as well so it can't include `..` or other potentially dangerous inputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should never use this include solution, because it can be vulnerable to [code injection](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Code_Injection).

Even using file_exists is not a good solution, because the attacker can try some files in your server that was not properly secured and gain access to them.

You should use a white list: a dictionary containing the files that the user can include referenced by an alias, like this:

```
$whiteList = array(
    "page1" => "/dir1/file1.php",
    "page2" => "/dirabc/filexyz.php"
)
if (array_key_exists($p, $whiteList)) {
    include_once($whiteList[$p]);
} else {
    die("wrong file");
}
```

In this way you do no expose the server files structure to the web and guarantee that only a file allowed by you can be included.

You must sanitize the `$p` before using it:

```
$p = filter_input(INPUT_GET, "p", FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
```

But depending on the keys that you use in the dictionary, other filters should be used... look at the [reference](http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.sanitize.php).

Comment: Thank you. I never knew I was leaving myself open to hacks. Even though I had to add a bunch of pages to the whitelist, I think this is the best option for me. Thank you so much for your help and information explaining what to do and what not to do.

Comment: I am very happy to help you! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
$filename = 'p'.$p.'/index.php';
```

Solution1:

```
if(!@include($filename)) throw new Exception("Failed to include ".$filename);
```

Solution2: Use file_exists - this checks whether a file or directory exists, so u can just check for directory as well

```
if (!file_exists($filename)) {
    echo "The file $filename does not exist";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if(!file_exists('p'.$p.'/index.php')) die('error');

require_once('p'.$p.'/index.php');
```